# Serialization and deserialization of SimpleGrantedAuthority problem in difference version of Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

There are some microservices that are authenticated by Spring Security OAuth2. The version of Spring Security of some of them are `4.2.3.release` and rest of them are `5.1.2.release` and the Authorization Server(UAA) is secured by `spring security 5.1.2.release` as same as Zuul gateway as OAuth2 Client. The grant type flow is `authorization_code` flow. The Resource Server configuration is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/Content/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/j-captcha.jpg*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/View/ScriptHeader/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/Scripts/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/download/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/NewTheme/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ErrorPages/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/landing/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/api/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/View/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

}
```

After authentication and auuthorization the following exception is raised in Resource Servers in which the version of spring security is `4.2.3.release`

> Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException:
>   org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
>   local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 510,
>   local class serialVersionUID = 420    at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1630)

Due to this error, I saw the content of SimpleGrantedAuthority class in both Spring Security 5.1.2.release, there is the following line:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 510L;
```

and Spring Security 4.2.3.release, there is the following line:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 420L;
```

Because of some reasons, I am not able to upgrade the `4.2.3.release` to `5.1.2.release` and because of the overhead cost of UAA to retrieve the `Pricipal`, I do not use the `RemoteTokenServices` instead of `DefaultTokenServices`.

How do I fix my problem?

Totally, what is standard way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Hi @reza-ramezani-matin did you manage to upgrade in the end? If so what did you end up doing?

Comment: hi @reza-ramezani-matin what was your solution to this issue?